# Unity - Creating a plane that you can deform on runtime creating a path

Tags: unity, optimization, mesh

So I'm doing this project which is similar to Castle Raid (https://youtu.be/ZiAv1smyCKM) And I'm having trouble implementing the path creation by deforming a mesh and making the players move on it. I tried many approaches which all till now seem to fail. I'm open to any suggestion and any kind of help.

Approaches I already tried:

1. Deforming the mesh by shifting the vertices inside a radius down and using a navmesh with agents to walk on the path. first, off it didn't seem like the game's mechanic which was based on physics as it seems.

```
    public void DeformThisPlane(Vector3 positionToDeform)
    {
        positionToDeform = transform.InverseTransformPoint(positionToDeform); 

        for (int i = 0; i < _verts.Length; i++)
        {
            var dist = (_verts[i] - positionToDeform).sqrMagnitude;

            if (dist < radius)
            {
                _verts[i] -= Vector3.up * power;
            }
        }
        
        _planeMesh.vertices = _verts;
    }
```

The result was very weird behavior for the agents while the navmesh was rebuilt every time the plane gets deformed.

[image: First Approach gif]

2. Then I tried Using physics by updating the mesh collider every time the plane gets deformed and then letting the physics engine do its thing.

```
    ...
        _planeMesh.vertices = _verts;
        Destroy(_lastMeshCollider);
        _lastMeshCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    }
```

As well the results weren't good because the players (balls) were getting stuck on the edges created by the deformation. and updating the mesh collider was taking resources to compute and lowered the performance.

[image: Second Approach gif]

3. I was desperate so I tried another solution that I was certain is not performant I created a cylinder in a blender and imported as many objects and added a trigger to delete them on the overlap. then Instantiated that object on the position of the deformation.

[image: Cylinder photo]

The results were not smooth as well and it froze my pc because of instantiating that many objects and checking for trigger and overlap. But it was the closest I got.

[image: Approach 3 gif]

Someone from the community suggested dragging the vertices down instead of shifting them which will surely smoothen the edges but we will get the same problem updating the collider.

If there's a shader approach that would help me please share and Thank you!

Comment: Myself, I wouldn't use navmesh and navmesh agents for this at all. I'd use a flow field for pathfinding. That way the whole swarm of agents can share the results of a single pathfinding pass, rather than each one making its own path queries.

Comment: @DMGregory the thing with pathfinding overall is that I don't think it fits the concept of the game shared a link on top which should be physics based.